# How to prevent toggling class to go on top of page in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a website where users can click on a link in the header and it toggles a class to make an element appear. This is working, but every time I try it the page goes back to the top. How can I prevent this?

This is my code:

```js
function openModal(e) {
  e.parentNode.classList.toggle("modal-open")
}
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p class="open" onclick="openModal(this)">Open</p>

  <div class="modal" onclick="openModal(this)">
    Content modal
  </div>
</header>
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me and doesn't jump to the top of the page when you click on open.  Can you edit the snippet and create a [mcve]  demoinstrating your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could fix the problem, it's because on the body I had a `width: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your CSS, do not use position: fixed unless it's very necessary. Instead use

```
position: absolute;
top: 0
```

Another thing I think it effects your code is the height:100vh

in short saying: there're nothing wrong in your JS, just alter the css:

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could fix the problem, it's because on the body I had a `width: 100%`